# Wireshark: Call MAC dissector from .lua plugin

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am trying to call specific protocol dissectors from my .lua plugin.
The line is:

```
Dissector.get("mac"):call(buf, pinfo, tree)
```

Some work (e.g. gtp) but others I need do not (e.g. mac for MAC, rsl for RSL). I looked at the epan/dissectors folder and tried other variations to no avail.

Anyone knows if the issue is finding the correct name of the protocol, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the answer I provided to this same question over at https://ask.wireshark.org/question/6288/call-mac-dissector-from-lua-plugin/, but copied here for convenience:

---

If you're looking for the correct protocol names, you can try running something like `tshark -G protocols | grep NAME` … where **NAME** is the name of the protocol you're looking for.  (Refer to the [tshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) man page for more details on the **-G** option.)

For example:

```
$ tshark -G protocols | grep RSL
Radio Signalling Link (RSL)     RSL     gsm_abis_rsl
```

So in the case of **RSL**, it looks like you'd need `Dissector.get("gsm_abis_rsl"):call(buf, pinfo,tree)`

Of course this doesn't always work, because the same search for **MAC** does find it:

```
$ tshark -G protocols | grep MAC
DOCSIS Mac Management   DOCSIS MAC MGMT docsis_mgmt
MACsec Key Agreement    EAPOL-MKA       mka
Radio Link Control, Medium Access Control, 3GPP TS44.060        GSM RLC MAC    gsm_rlcmac
ISMACryp Protocol       ISMACRYP        ismacryp
**MAC     MAC     mac**
MAC-LTE MAC-LTE mac-lte
mac-lte-framed  MAC-LTE-FRAMED  mac-lte-framed
MAC-NR  MAC-NR  mac-nr
MikroTik MAC-Telnet Protocol    MAC-Telnet      mactelnet
MAC Control     MACC    macc
802.1AE Security tag    MACsec  macsec
MPLS-MAC        Media Access Control (MAC) Address Withdrawal over Static Pseudowire    mpls_mac
WiMax MAC Management Message    MGMT MSG        wmx.mgmt
DCOM IRemoteActivation  REMACT  remact
Token-Ring Media Access Control TR MAC  trmac
WiMax Generic/Type1/Type2 MAC Header Messages   WiMax Generic/Type1/Type2 MAC Header (hdr)      wmx.hdr
WiMAX MAC-PHY over Ethernet     WiMAX MAC-PHY   wimaxmacphy
```

In this case, it seems you need to look at the source code (unless there's some other method I'm not aware of) in order to find the dissector that's actually registered.

```
$ grep "proto_register_protocol" packet-*.c | grep "\"MAC\""
packet-umts_mac.c:    proto_umts_mac = proto_register_protocol("MAC", "MAC", "mac");

$ grep register_dissector packet-umts_mac.c
    register_dissector("mac.fdd.rach", dissect_mac_fdd_rach, proto_umts_mac);
    register_dissector("mac.fdd.fach", dissect_mac_fdd_fach, proto_umts_mac);
    register_dissector("mac.fdd.pch", dissect_mac_fdd_pch, proto_umts_mac);
    register_dissector("mac.fdd.dch", dissect_mac_fdd_dch, proto_umts_mac);
    register_dissector("mac.fdd.edch", dissect_mac_fdd_edch, proto_umts_mac);
    register_dissector("mac.fdd.edch.type2", dissect_mac_fdd_edch_type2, proto_umts_mac);
    register_dissector("mac.fdd.hsdsch", dissect_mac_fdd_hsdsch, proto_umts_mac);
```